# A button that calls the nested accordion of the first one

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a nested accordion section in my site (WordPress) and I want by clicking one button to open the first accordion and then the second one. Is there a coded way to do this?

```
<div class="button">
   <a href="mysite.com/1st_page#1st_id, mysite.com/1st_page#2nd_id">Read more</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open 2 links just write this:

```
<div class="button">
    <a onclick="window.open('http://example.com/2nd_page#2nd_id');" href="http://example.com/1st_page#1st_id">Read more</a>
</div>
```

1st will be opened in an origin tab and second in another. But for some users second tab can be blocked by the browser until user allows popups from your site.